# build html snippets with JSON data and inject the snippets into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I'm building a single page app similar to pininterest where I fetch JSON data in increments of 20. My project does not support Angularjs, backbone mustache or any such framework or libraries.

I need help in identifying a solution for my problems listed below:

1. I want to decouple my html for the tiles (with images and without) as templates.
2. On receiving the JSON data first 20 items, I want to build the tiles and inject it inside my main index.html
3. How do I make calls to get JSON data starting from 21-40 and 40-60. The JSON data has numbering property called rank:1, rank:2 etc..

I'm looking for a front-end solution with Javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing what I do with my SPA applications. I implement a very similar feature on my blog's home view, http://love2dev.com. I don't do paging for new tiles though.

You are correct, you do not need any bulky framework to execute what you need. As for templating I use either MUSTACHE or something based on this article, http://tech.pro/tutorial/1743/javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-lines. I actually use the 20 line function in my Blog. In my new SPA book I use MUSTACHE, it is up to you.

To call the next 20 records you would need to configure your API to allow you to retrieve a paged dataset. This can be done with a querystring parameter, or a route variable. It is up to you. Normally you have a parameter for page # and total records. If you need help with the actual AJAX layer I would look at rolling your own or using reqwest, https://github.com/ded/reqwest?source=cc.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will look at the links provided and get back if I have any questions.

Comment: I saw the template engine link and the requirement for his code to work, I need to embedded my HTML snippet inside the js code as a var template. My HTML snippet is pretty complex and about 70-80 lines and I have more than 30-40 data objects which I need to update based on the kind of data object. Is it possible to keep the template external .html file and reference that in the var template = "/pathto/partial/htmlfile" ?